# Facebook Unity SDK AppRequest not showing notification [Android]

Tags: unity-game-engine, notifications, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-app-requests

I am making game with Unity v5.2.1 + Facebook Unity SDK v7.2.0 for android. My game have feature to invite friends. This feature implemented by calling `FB.AppRequest()` function.

It works quite well, but the problem is my friend not receiving an android notification. The only way to know that the invitation is sent, is by opening facebook android app and click the world icon (notification page) on facebook.

How can i show an android notification when invitation is sent to friend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook does not do that for you automatically. You need to implement this system yourself.

Here is how I would do it:

- A sends AppRequest to B in you app
- In the callback, you know the target ids from the "to" list, report that to your server if you have one (and it is required for this system to work)
- Server sends a push notification to the target device that is associated to the target facebook user id